# how to add temporary environment path using node.js

Tags: node.js, flutter

What i tried is :

```
  exec( "export PATH=/Users/shubhamkumar/flutter/bin:$PATH",
 (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err); // node couldn't execute the command
        return;
      }
      // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    });
```

but it's not setting the path temporary.
when i am trying to execute this

```
 exec("flutter doctor", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err); // node couldn't execute the command
        return;
      }
      // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    });
```

it says 'command not found: flutter'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily set env variables by setting the `process.env` object. Try the following (not tested):

```
process.env.PATH = '/Users/shubhamkumar/flutter/bin:' + process.env.PATH

exec("flutter doctor", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err); // node couldn't execute the command
        return;
      }
      // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    });
```

Comment: getting this error on console '/bin/sh: flutter: command not found'

Comment: As you are on a unix based system, the `PATH` variable is capitalized. I corrected the code above ... additionaly the seperator is a `:`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sebastian